# Запуск двух ботов одновременно discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

У меня есть два бота - два файла.
В первом файле переменная client, во втором client2.
Я пытаюсь запустить оба этих бота одновременно с помощью третьего файла с вот таким вот кодом:

```
import bot_1
import bot_2

bot_1.client.run('token')
bot_2.client2.run('token')
```

Если весь ход моих мыслей не правильный, то как тогда запустить двух ботов одновременно?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
bot_1.client.start()
bot_2.client2.run()
```

Comment: В первой строке получаю ошибку:
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Нельзя использовать асинхронную функцию, вне функции, что я могу с этим сделать?

Comment: Тогда я не знаю :D. Дело в том, что я просто забил вашу проблему в интернет и он мне выдал тот ответ, который я написал. Простите за дезинформация)

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as Discord_bot
from asyncio import create_task, run


class Bot(Discord_bot):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"{self.user} connected")


async def main():
    task_1 = create_task(Bot().start('token'))
    task_2 = create_task(Bot().start('token'))

    await task_1
    await task_2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```

У меня отлично работает, тестировал. Если что-то не так, задайте вопрос, отвечу)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]